# SQL grammar & Snowflake's query parser

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(Submitting Q&A string to answer a commonly occurring question)

---

Is there any documentation on the SQL grammar that Snowflake's query parser is implemented? I would like to have at least a semi-automated way to convert some of my large queries from a different SQL dialect to Snowflake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Response #1:***

The Snowflake documentation has all of the commands and functions available in Snowflake.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference-commands.html

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference-functions.html

---

***Response #2:***

As far as I am aware, there is no automated way but query editors can highlight issues when other dialects are used when the session is connected to Snowflake.

Another way is to quickly convert schema using SqlDBM and then match what data types changed.

For reference:

SqlDBM is compatible with MS SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Snowflake and Amazon Redshift
You can convert projects between MS SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Snowflake and Amazon Redshift

---

*Feel free to comment with additional resources or other helpful ideas...  -G*

Comment: For an automated way to migrate queries, views, tables and stored procedures from Teradata and Oracle I recomment you take a look at [SnowConvert](https://www.mobilize.net/snowconvert). 
Disclosure: I work at Mobilize